# Response for preflight is invalid (redirect), browser keep using OPTION method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

so im trying to do this:

```
if (userPass == "0" && emailPass == "0" && dniPass == "0"){

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "text/plain",
            dataType : "text",
            url: "..php/newUser.php",
            data: { uid: uId, Plan : plan, Name : name, Dni : dni, Email : email, User : user, Pass : pass},
            success: doneReg

        });

    }
}
```

But i keep getting "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" although im making the request to my own server. The browser keeps using the OPTIONS method.

I looked in google and everywhere they said it was a CORS problem that was solved by indicating that the content-type was text / plain but as you can see in the code I'm trying to do that but it does not work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

doneReg is the callback to get the data.

newUser.php respones is just a plain text.

The data is just Strings.

Comment: The `..php` part of your url is being interpreted as a domain name. Change it to `../php` if you're trying to access a `php` folder one level up from the current page.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Already tried that, still the same error

Comment: The php file is two levels up of where the .js is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background: your backend *must not* answer with redirect to `OPTIONS` request.

Possible root cause:

1. you are requesting wrong URL. Open Developer Tools in your browser and check actual URL is requesting(you can see it at Network tab).
2. your backend is configured in wrong way(then you should get the same error in other cases)